# How to use apache mod-rewrite to remove trailing semi-colon on cookie?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, cookie

We have the following cookie set by a product:

```
Set-Cookie: SSOCookie=T7ngsCmzC2FEq5p2a7o%3D; path=/; domain=.demo.com;
```

We would like to use Apache to remove the trailing `;` which doesn't match the Cookie specification. Can we use mod_rewrite? How?

We are using Apache/2.0.47.

Answer (score 2):

As you are referring to a `Set-Cookie` header, this must be in reference to a response being sent by the product to which you refer.

Assuming you cannot fix the product nor can the vendor, you will need to modify the response headers as required. You can't achieve this with mod_rewrite; it is for manipulating request URLs only.

[mod_headers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html) is described as as being for the "[c]ustomization of HTTP request and response headers". Examine the documentation for the 'edit' action.